# Forever young? (aka age is off by one year)

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, network-profile, user-age

I turned 38 almost a month ago. However, my [network profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/201110/shadow-wizard) still showing me as 37 years old:

> [image]

Trying to update the profile info didn't help. (and hence the different avatar.)

I do have proper Birthday field in all my per-site profiles:

> [image]

While I'm flattered Stack Exchange thinks I'm younger than my real age, I would like this to be fixed and show that real age.

Comment: `yyyy/mm/dd` - November isn't here yet.

Comment: @Oded lol, silly me! But it can be easily "reproduced", and might be even worthy an answer... :)

Comment: No repro, in that... given the right date, it produces the right age ;)

Comment: So typical [tag:status-bydesign], or [tag:status-blonde-moment]... @Oded

Comment: You are that old @Sha?

Comment: @Pat lol, I guess.... though there is always the chance my parents faked my birthdate... :-D

Answer (score 4):

As Oded has [kindly mentioned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/283148/forever-young-aka-age-is-off-by-one-year#comment917773_283148), the date format is yyyy/mm/dd as also shown in the  placeholder:

> [image]

Somehow  I just missed that, thus what I thought is July 11<sup>th</sup> was actually November 7<sup>th</sup> as far as SE knows.

The only bug was in my head. Cheers, and hope not many will fall in this same pit. :)